# Applied Eventually Consistency and Race Conditions

Tags: concurrency, runtime, microservices, verification, eventual-consistency

I have a question regarding the effect of eventually consistent (EC) microservice systems.

Imagine we have a booking system - a *user-service A* and *booking-service B*. Each service has its own database. Imagine the system does a concurrent booking of the same resource for distinct users at the same time. Lets assume we have a Runtime Verification System checking the concurrent booking.

Would it be possible that the monitor does not realize the concurrent booking at B, because the update in the database is done delayed because of the EC mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `Booking Service` is the source of truth (presumably) for whether or not the resource is available to book.  So, that service should be pretty clear on allowing the first booking request to happen and rejecting the second.

In a case like this, where "first come first served" is the requirement, you'd want an intermediate state that would wait for a response from the `Booking Service` and update the `User Service` only when a response has been received.

If your architecture is set up right, `User Service` shouldn't be calling `Booking Service` directly anyway - it should be communicating through a messaging plane.  As such, when the `User` clicks "Book Now," you could generate a `resourceBookingRequested` message and submit it to the queue.  You'd acknowledge this request has been queued to the user and update their UI to "Awaiting Booking Confirmation..." or something similar.

Once the booking is accepted, or rejected, the `User Service` subscribes to the resulting message and updates the UI (and/or takes other actions like sending an email) to let the user know their request succeeded or didn't.

Comment: But what if the user cannot wait and needs an immediate response because of emergent cases like booking a rescue service? Ok here than would be the question why he have time to select options, but nevertheless...so this EC should not be applied in this setting? but if it would be applied, would the scenerio anyway be possible?

I am focussing on scenarios where RV can fail in microservice systems, and this is what I had in mind.

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining your scenario.  What does "immediate response" mean?  Your `Booking Service` could be called directly by the UI (which should be a separate thing from the `User Service`) and return an error if no longer available.  You can't really get much more immediate than that.

Comment: With immediate response I mean, not to let the user wait with the "Awaiting Booking Confirmation..." but rather to perform directly after the request the booking check at the 'User Service'. I mean the idea of the EC is to improve the availability. When I do this Booking Check at 'User Service' this would improve far more the availiability or not?